# If there are 2 tags that are the same thing is it ok to retag all posts with them to use only 1 tag

Tags: discussion, etiquette, tags

I'm specifically thinking of the tags `lwp` and `perl-lwp` these both mean exactly the same thing and as far as google is concerned `lwp` has only one meaning. I'm wondering if it would be appropriate to retag posts to only one of these 2 so in the end only one exists?

Comment: What about all the `Lotus Word Pro` questions?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming [[lwp]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lwp) and [[perl-lwp]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl-lwp) are actually used interchangeably, it's definitely ok and happens all the time; there's actually a couple 10k tools specifically for finding new synonymous tags and easily retagging them, and a moderator tool to merge tags immediately. If there's a lot of retags needed, you can request here that a moderator do the retagging instead with that tool (just tag the question [[retag-request]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=retag-request&sort=info&pagesize=15)). You can also propose a tag synonym on the [info page of one of the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=perl-lwp&sort=info&pagesize=50); there's more info about tag synonyms [on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)

Comment: What 10k tools are you talking about? AFAIK there is only *"questions with newly created tags"*.

Comment: @Georg And the [inline tagging interface](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/), which is massively useful for retagging

Comment: Ah, i forgot that was 10k only. So we have two, not a couple.

Comment: @Georg Huh? A couple is "approximately two". If I'd known it'd be so analyzed I would've combed through all the 10k tools and said "I am confident that the number of tagging-related tools is precisely two", but at the time I was thinking "well there's a list of new tags, and the retagging interface, and maybe some other stuff I don't use, so I'll say 'a couple'"

Comment: Reading *"a couple"* (i.e. *some*) i was confused as to what other tools you might be thinking of. It seems to imply that there are more. Note that i didn't criticize, just clarified that for me and others that might have the same confusion.